# Combine two tables with same DB SELECT statements

Tags: sql, database

Most people instruct that you shouldn't make a bunch of DB connections in one request. So i tried to combine the following tables (`car` & `bike`) and failed. Any idea how to combine both and avoid duplicate entries if i use the following php while functions?

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE price NOT LIKE '' order by id asc";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while( $val = mysqli_fetch_array($qry) ) {

    if ( ( ($val['city'] == $to ) && ($val['airport'] == $from) ) || ( ($val['airport'] == $to ) && ($val['country'] == $from) ) ) {
    
    $distance = $val['distance'];
    
    } 
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM bike WHERE price NOT LIKE '' order by id asc";
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while( $val = mysqli_fetch_array($qry) ) {

    if ( ( ($val['village'] == $to ) && ($val['airport'] == $from) ) || ( ($val['airport'] == $to ) && ($val['country'] == $from) ) ) {
    
        $distance = $val['distance'];
    
    } 
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE price NOT LIKE '' order by id asc
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM bike WHERE price NOT LIKE '' order by id asc
```

Comment: Can you define what a "duplicate" here by means of some sample data?

Comment: for example the same `name` for each car and bike

Comment: Why duplicates should be removed? What is the logic in removing some data from one table in favor of another?

Comment: Please add sample data which helps to explain your question.

Comment: This is a textbook XY problem. Almost everything about this code is wrong. Both queries are using a single connection, so there is no point in joining them. Both queries are awfully inefficient, doing filtering on the PHP side instead of the database. You need to ask a completely different question, regarding this 'distance' calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates, that being defined as two cars or bikes having the same name, you may use a union between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT name FROM car
UNION
SELECT name FROM bike;
```

If the `car` and `bike` tables happen to have different structure (i.e. different columns and/or types of columns), then you would need to specify *which* columns you want to combine to have in the final result set.

Comment: yes they have different columns - any example how to specify them

Comment: One query gives one set of columns/records.  You would need to post table structure and the output you want.  But generally, a `UNION` might be what you want here.

Comment: i think i made a mistake with writing "avoid multiples entries" in `name` - im using Select * because my PHP while function checks a few columns like `if ( (($conn['city']==$to ) && ($conn['airport']==$from)) || (($conn['airport']==$to ) && ($conn['country']==$from))...`

Comment: I can't comment further without seeing your data.  But please update your question with this information rather than leaving further comments here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`, which will also remove duplicates. Also `LIKE` is not needed because you aren't using a pattern:

```
SELECT name 
FROM car 
WHERE price <> '' 
ORDER BY id asc

UNION 

SELECT name  
FROM bike 
WHERE price <> '' 
ORDER BY id asc
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` will only be applied/recognized at the end of the union, so the first query's `ORDER BY` would be ignored.